# Find the irreducible components of $V(x - yz, xz - y^2)$.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I think I have an answer but I'm looking for some verification.

Since $x - yz = 0$, then I can rewrite my problem as $V(x - yz, yz^2 - y^2)$.

This is equal to $V(x - yz, y) \cup V(x - yz, z^2 - y)$.

Then $V(x - yz, y) = V(x, y)$ is irreducible.

Also, $V(x - yz, z^2 - y) = V(x - z^3, z^2 - y)$ is also irreducible, since the corresponding coordinate ring will be $\mathbb{C}[z],$ which is an integral domain.

So the irreducible components are $V(x, y)$ and $V(x - z^3, z^2 - y).$

Comment: $\langle x-z^3,z^2-y\rangle$ is the intersection of a quadric and a cubic, and by bezout it is of degree six. That is, you get the twisted cubic doubly, which is fine if you want a set theoretic answer, and not an ideal theoretic one. The twisted cubic, singly, is $\langle z^2-y,x-yz,xz-y^2\rangle$. (Two quadrics intersect to give something of degree four, so you need three quadrics to cut out the twisted cubic; any two of the three yields (different!) secant lines as well. In intersection theory (where the bezout theorem lives) this expresses the degrees $2\cdot 2=3+1$.)

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Among your three generators for the ideal of the twisted cubic singly, the third is redundant: $(z^2-y)y+(x-yz)z=xz-y^2$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland In fact, as far as I can see, the ideal you described for "singly" and the one at the beginning of your comment for "doubly" are equal; every generator of either of these ideals lies in the other one. I think you might be using Bezout's theorem for plane curves and applying it to surfaces in 3-space.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: My confusion comes from thinking in ${\Bbb P}^3$ in terms of $\langle z^2-yw, xw-yz, xz-y^2 \rangle$ (which by the way is set-theoretically defined by $\langle yw-z^2,x(xw-yz)-y(xz-y^2)\rangle$ and not $\langle xw^2-z^3,z^2-yw\rangle$.)

Comment: Your argument is perfect.